# How to Add a Material to a Lamp in the Blender Game Engine

Tags: node-editor, game-engine, lighting

I'm making a game in UPBGE mainly it has a day/night cycle. I made a street lamp with a spotlight. I'm asking for a way to use nodes in for the lamps in the game engine.

Comment: Lamps can't use nodes in Internal/BGE, not even EEVEE supports lamp shader nodes yet

Answer (score 0):

If you're still trying to do this, or if someone else is trying to, you can animate the brightness of the spotlight and use logic bricks (or python) to play that animation.